# Chosing next relative in Python BeautifulSoup with automation

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

First of all - I'm creating xml document with python BeautifulSoup.

Currently, what I'm trying to create, is very similar to this example.

```
<options>
    <opt name='string'>ContentString</opt>
    <opt name='string'>ContentString</opt>
    <opt name='string'>ContentString</opt>
</options>
```

Notice, that there should be only one tag, called `name`.

As options can be much more in count, and different as well, I decided to create little python function, which could help me create such result.

```
array = ['FirstName','SecondName','ThirdName'] 
# This list will be guideline for function to let it know, how much options will be in result, and how option tags will be called.

def create_options(array):
    soup.append(soup.new_tag('options'))
    if len(array) > 0: # It's small error handling, so you could see, if given array isn't empty by any reason. Optional.
        for i in range(len(array)):
            soup.options.append(soup.new_tag('opt'))
            # With beatifullsoup methods, we create opt tags inside options tag. Exact amount as in parsed array.
        counter = 0
        # There's option to use python range() method, but for testing purposes, current approach is sufficient enough.
        for tag in soup.options.find_all():
            soup.options.find('opt')['name'] = str(array[counter])
            # Notice, that in this part tag name is assigned only to first opt element. We'll discuss this next.
            counter += 1
        print len(array), ' options were created.'
    else:
        print 'No options were created.'
```

You notice, that in function, tag assignment is handled by `for` loop, which, unfortunately, assigns all different tag names to first option in options element.

BeautifulSoup has `.next_sibling` and `.previous_sibling`, which can help me in this task.
As they describe by name, with them I can access next or previous sibling in element. So, by this example:

`soup.options.find('opt').next_sibling['name'] = str(array[counter])`

We can access second child of options element. So, if we add .next_sibling to each soup.items.find('opt'), we could then move from first element to next.
Problem is, that by finding option element in options with:

`soup.options.find('opt')`

each time we access first option. But my function is willing to access with each item in list, next option as well. So it means, as more items are in list, more `.next_sibling` methods it must add to first option.

In result, with logic I constructed, with 4th or further item in list, accessing relevant option for assigning it's appropriate tag, should look like this:

`soup.options.find('opt').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling['name'] = str(array[counter])`

And now we are ready to my questions:

1st. As I didn't found any other kind of method, how to do it with Python BeautifulSoup methods, I'm not sure, that my approach still is only way. Is there any other method?

2st. How could I achieve result by this approach, if as my experiments show me, that I can't put variable inside method row? (So I could multiply methods)

```
#Like this
thirdoption = .next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
#As well, it's not quite possible, but it's just example.
soup.options.find('opt').next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling['name'] = str(array[counter])
```

3st. May be I read BeautifulSoup documentation badly, and just didn't found method, which could help me in this task?

Comment: BeautifulSoup's strengths lie in providing access to HTML documents, mainly. While you *can* use it for XML, and *can* use it to add new data, it's not the best choice for such tasks, perhaps. Have you considered using `ElementTree` or `lxml` instead?

Comment: And why not just use `.find_all('opt')` to get a *list* of `<opt>` elements?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, of course. I worked with ET methods too, and they are nice too. Thing is, ET is little bit... 'bulkier' which in no way is bad, of course. What I'm trying to achieve by this question, is mention, that, perhaps, python BeautifulSoup could give more options, not mainly aiming for document parsing.

Comment: Um... oh... hm, I didn't considered to store list of `.find_all('opt')` into variable... should try now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Storing all options in variable doesn't change method, how BeautifulSoup should do it's job. (I know, obvious. Just clarification.) That said, then I'll try then achieve my task with ET methods. Later, as I'll prepare some results, I'll put them in answer, so to remind at least myself, that many modules has many pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve result, ignoring BeatifulSoup methods.
Python has element tree methods, which were sufficient enough to work with.

So, let me show the example code, and explain it, what it does. Comments provide explanation more precisely.

```
"""
Before this code, there goes soup xml document generation. Except part, I mentioned in topic, we just create empty options tags in document, thus, creating almost done document.
Right after that, with this little script, we will use basic python provided element tree methods.
"""

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET_tree = ET.parse("exported_file.xml")
# Here we import exactly the same file, we opened with soup. Exporting can be done in different file, if you wish.
ET_root = ET_tree.getroot()

for position, opt in enumerate(item.find('options')):
# Position is pretty important, as this will remove 'counter' thing in for loop, I was using in code in first example. Position will be used for getting out exact items from array, which works like template for our option tag names.
    opt.set('name', str(array[position]))
    opt.text = 'text'
# Same way, with position, we can get data from relevant array, provided, that they are inherited or connected in same way.

tree = ET.ElementTree(ET_root).write('exported_file.xml',encoding="UTF-8",xml_declaration=True)
# This part was something, I researched before quite lot. This code will help save xml document with utf-8 encoding, which is very important.
```

This approach is pretty inefficient, as for achieving same result, I could use ET for everything.
Thought, BeatifulSoup prepares document in nice output, which in any way is very neat, as element-tree creates files for software friendly only look.